# nftables rate limit whitelist

Tags: linux, firewall, nftables

Following this [article](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_nftables_to_limit_the_amount_of_connections) on nftables *Blocking IP addresses that attempt more than ten new incoming TCP connections within one minute* how would one add a whitelist like `ip saddr != { ip1, ip2,... }`?

```
table ip filter {
        set denylist {
                type ipv4_addr
                flags dynamic,timeout
                timeout 1m
        }

        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                ip protocol tcp ct state new,untracked update @denylist { ip saddr limit rate over 10/minute } drop
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
# rate limits
ip saddr != { $IP1, $IP2 } ip protocol tcp ct state new,untracked limit rate over 2/second update @denylist { ip saddr }
ip saddr @denylist drop
```